# How to select element from tuple by index in list?

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, modulo

I want to select elements from a list, [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] once the first, than the second, than again the first and so on. 
I figured that i could use zip to add a counter in front of the pairs and use modulo to select the part, and now my list looks like this:

```
let a = [(0,[1,2]),(1,[3,4]),(2,[5,6]),(3,[7,8]),(4,[9,10])]
```

but how can I now select the elements?

the pseudocode would be

```
for each tuple in list:
      first part of tuple is the selector, second part is the pair
      if selector mod 2 : choose pair[0] else choose pair[1]
```

the output for the list a should be: 1,4,5,7,9

Comment: But if it is always a pair, then it is usually better to use 2-tuples, since then we enforce that by the type.

Comment: Secondly I have the idea that that you probably want to select it the opposite way: in case `selector mod 2` is `1`, then you probably want to select `pair[1]`?

Comment: You can also zip with `cycle [True, False]` so that you don't have to use `mod x 2`. Anyway, you should use `map` on this list (or yours).

Comment: @chi: can you add an example? I dont understand how to use this

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem: maybe, i haven't figured out what I realy need to do, I only know that I have to select alternating values; but I guess I can't use tuples because the input is in list form already

Comment: @user2567875 You can `map ... (zip .. ..)` or more directly `zipWith .. .. ..` as Daniel Wagner did below. In each case you need a suitable function for the `map` or `zipWith`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
> zipWith (!!) [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]] (cycle [0,1])
[1,4,5,8,9]
```

If you know you're working with lists of length two inside, you should probably be using pairs instead.

```
> zipWith ($) (cycle [fst, snd]) [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)]
[1,4,5,8,9]
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain what the !! and $ do here? I am still struggling with the haskell concepts in general

Comment: @user2567875 You can use [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to find documentation for Haskell functions.

Answer (score 1):

I like @DanielWagner answer a lot. The first is so simple and effective. His second is a just a little harder to understand but simple, too. When theories are simple, it increases their veracity. Here is my sorry solution but it does use your structure. (Association lists are tuples. It was suggested you use tuples but for this, what you have and probably need is okay.)

```
a = [(0,[1,2]),(1,[3,4]),(2,[5,6]),(3,[7,8]),(4,[9,10])]

[if even i then x else y | (i,(x:y:z)) <- a]

[1,4,5,8,9]
```